# Field level comparision in MYSQL language

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows

```
ID CITY PARENTID
1  VIZ     1
2  HYD     1
3  CHE     1
6  MUM     3
15 KOL     2
```

I need a SQL that first compares the ID field with each value in the field PARENTID and reverts back to ID and picks the corresponding CITY for that field.

For Example, when ID value is 3, it checks its corresponding PARENTID which is 1 and then it should return the CITY value which is corresponding to 1 in the ID field which is VIZ.,

One more example is for ID 6 and its corresponding PARENTID is 3 and it will again check the ID field for 3 and returns its corresponding CITY which is CHE.,

Similarly for ID 15 the CITY should be HYD,

Can this be captured in MYSQL using a SQL Query rather than using any anonymous Block or Stored Procedure??

I created a SQL with SELF JOIN as below

```
    SELECT DISTINCT G.CITY FROM TBLGEOMARKET G,TBLGEOMARKET GM
    WHERE GM.ID = G.PARENTID;
```

TEST SQL:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT G.CITY FROM TBLGEOMARKET G,TBLGEOMARKET GM
    WHERE GM.ID = G.PARENTID AND GM.PARENTID = 15;
```

Here the Output is KOL which is not correct as its giving the City corresponding to ID rather than checking the PARENTID in ID and giving the result, which is HYD in our scenario.

I'm missing some clause here, any information absolutely appreciated.

Comment: What about for city 1? _Sidenote, implicit "comma" join notation has been out of favor for decades at this point._ Also, how should your desired results look?

Comment: Understandable, I will make sure time

Comment: Your test query seems to be mixing up parent and child; `GM.ID = G.PARENTID` suggests GM is the parent, but you're selecting `G.CITY` suggesting G is the parent. Also, if you're looking for the parent of city 15, the condition would be `ID=15` not `PARENTID = 15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
select t2.city 
from TBLGEOMARKET t1 inner join TBLGEOMARKET t2
on t2.id = t1.parentid
where t1.id = 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d8JuqMLtU55pk5eX8dqxWs/0).
Or you can use a subquery which makes the code simpler to read and not less efficient:

```
select city 
from TBLGEOMARKET 
where id = (select parentid from TBLGEOMARKET where id = 15)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d8JuqMLtU55pk5eX8dqxWs/1).

Result:

```
| city |
| ---- |
| VIZ  |
```

Comment: Added a Test SQL for better understanding, here I replicated my scenario of million rows with a simple table 5 row table :)

Comment: @user10531062 test these 2 queries and choose the one that you find easier or more efficient.